# How to pass parameter from power bi query to sp to get dataset from ssms

Tags: powerbi

I have a procedure which returns a dataset:

```
EXEC [dbo].[retStudentDetails]
        @x = 1
```

Result:

```
id  fname   score

1   A       32
```

Query in power bi:

```
Source = Sql.Database("KALPESH-W8", "sample", [Query="EXEC#(tab) [dbo].[retStudentDetails]#(lf)#(tab)#(tab)@x = "&identity&""])
```

However, this gives me the following error:

> Expression.Error: We cannot apply operator & to types Text and Number.

Details:

```
Operator=&amp;

Left=EXEC    [dbo].[retStudentDetails]

    @x = 

Right=1*
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is presented here:

```
Operator=&amp;

Left=EXEC    [dbo].[retStudentDetails]

    @x = // text and empty!

Right=1* // Number
```

Where your left side is of the type `Text` and your left side is of the type `Number`.

And as your error expression is `Expression.Error: We cannot apply operator & to types Text and Number.` This is because you cannot apply the `&` between numbers and text, they must be the same datatype.